# "jekyll serve --watch" doesn't regenerate automatically

Tags: jekyll

I'm working locally on a website that was build with Jekyll, and watching doesn't auto-regenerate changes I do in the code.

jekyll 2.2.0

ruby 2.1.1p76 *via rvm*

configuration file I use is default one from http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/

Any suggestions? Thanks!

UPDATE #1: looks like something wrong in other area (gems? node.js?). Another project with Compass also unwatchible at the moment.

UPDATE #2: problem was solved after installation of "listen" gem.

Comment: Jekyll shouldn't use Compass or Node. If you edited the config file, you will need to restart the server manually. If you're still having issues, let me know what jekyll outputs when your files are being watched.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy yes, I still have the issue. In output I have two lines: 1) /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.2.0/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:46: warning: Unsupported encoding nil ignored 2) /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.2.0/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:136: warning: Unsupported encoding nil ignored

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's causing this issue, but sometimes you can solve issues like this by using a `Gemfile` with `bundle exec`. Try putting the gems you need into a `Gemfile`, and then run `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` to only use those gems.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy after experimenting with different combinations of versions of ruby and jekyll, figured out that I don't have a "listen" gem. After installation of it auto regeneration works well.

Comment: Nice! I'll add what I said as an answer, since it may be useful to others in the future.

Comment: If your problem is solved, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case after experimenting with different combinations of versions of Ruby and Jekyll, I figured out that I don't have a "listen" gem. After installation of it auto regeneration works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can often solve issues like this by using a `Gemfile` with `bundle exec` to ensure that all necessary gems are installed. Try putting the gems you need into a `Gemfile`, and then run `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` to only use those gems.

**Note:** This answer is based off my previous comment.